# jquery cache php ajax requests

Tags: php, jquery, caching

Im having a problem that is slowing down some of my ajax requests.

Using jquery I make an ajax call to a php script that queries the database runs some scripts and then returns the data.

Since im querying lots of data and formatting as well sometimes it takes 3-8 secs to return and decreases user experience.

How can I cache my php so it can return a cache result and only refresh the cache when a user makes a change.

Also some querys return different results based on what user is logged in. So I would need to cache the php ajax request/per user.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some information about [MySql caching in PHP](http://benmetcalfe.com/blog/2005/12/mysql-database-caching-in-php/)

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to use Zend_Cache to cache the returned code. A sample workflow would be:

```
$cache = Zend_Cache::factory($frontendName,
                         $backendName,
                         $frontendOptions,
                         $backendOptions);

$data = $cache->load('member-'.$id);

if (false === $data) {
    {.. process normally populating $data ..}

    $cache->save($data, 'member-'.$id);
}

{.. return $data formatted ..}
```

To remove the cached data if its been updated:

```
$cache = Zend_Cache::factory($frontendName,
                         $backendName,
                         $frontendOptions,
                         $backendOptions);

$cache->remove('member-'.$id);
```

Reference http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.html

Answer (score 0):

Time to install memcache: http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php